# I am trying to spit out a list in Meteor of an array I am keeping; not showing

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an array in my appname.js file that looks like this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: [
      { text: "This is task 1" },
      { text: "This is task 2" },
      { text: "This is task 3" }
    ]
  });

}
```

I have a folder "views", in the client folder, that I am keeping a "services.html" file in.  In that file, I have:

```
<template name="services">
              <ul>
                {{#each tasks}}
                  {{> task}}
                {{/each}}
              </ul>
</template>

<template name="task">
<li>{{text}}</li>
<template>
```

However, the tasks are not showing up in the view.  What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong template.It should be `Template.services.helper` instead of `Template.body.helper`

Comment: hm that's not what it has in the example in the meteor tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates

Also, it gave me an error, saying unexpected token